# Why is my answer for height negative?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Question is simple. A ball is thrown upwards with initial velocity  $v_0$.  How high does it go up?
Assume down is negative and up is positive and no air resistance.

KE at bottom = PE at the top:
$\frac12  m \times v_0^2 = m (-9.8)\times h$
which in turn implies $h$ will be negative.

So question is we assumed up is positive and why are we getting a negative height.

My guess is that we are dealing with energy which is a scalar quantity and hence signs should not be used. Not sure of this though.

Comment: I believe this post should be reopened as it asks for clarifications on a difficult concept: how to correctly define the sign of the potential energy.

Comment: In pretty much all physics contexts, the constant $g = 9.81\, \rm{m/s}$, with no negative sign. It is a combination of positive constants $GM_\bigoplus/R_\bigoplus^2$

Comment: Money is a scalar quantity, yet it is advisable to use signs when considering earnings and spendings.

Answer (score 7):

The error is with your sign in the potential energy, or alternatively with your sign for $g$.  Your right hand side $mgh$ should increase as $h$ increases, but with $g=-9.8$ the potential energy will decrease as you increase the height.  In other words, your expression for PE should be $-mgh$ if you use $g=-9.8$ and you take vertical up to be increasing heights.

Comment: it makes sense! but do you think is it reasonable to ignore signs when dealing with scalar quantities?

Comment: no.  do not ignore signs: it is a bad move that will get you in trouble.  Use the physics of the problem for sanity checks on the signs of the quantities in your problem.

Comment: @rasdocus  note that even if it is a scalar the potential energy can be positive or negative: the scalar nature of the quantity does not enter into this.

Comment: In general , I use negative energy for sources of energy and +ve for consumers of energy.

Comment: $U = mg(h-h_0) \ne m(-g)(h-h_0)$ So the slope of the line differs from the (arbitrary) definition of the intercept.

Comment: @JEB, please elaborate your comment. I did not fully get it

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I slightly disagree regarding signs. If there are several minus signs you might miss in a problem, but you know what sign the answer is, you can freely ignore _all the minus signs_, then just slap whatever sign you know is right on the answer. Of course, if there are two things you have to add together and you don't know their relative signs, or if you don't know the sign of the output, you should carefully keep track of all the signs. But you can speed up your problem solving by ignoring them when you can.

Comment: @AXensen true but this is the kind of shortcut that should be reserved for experienced users: incorrectly  applied it becomes a short circuit to an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 3):

The potential energy difference between point $A$ and $B$ is defined in terms of the work of a conservative force ${\bf F}$ on any path from $A$ to $B$:
$$
U(A)-U(B) = W_{AB} = \int_A^B  {\bf F} \cdot {\mathrm d}{\bf r}. 
$$
If ${\bf F} $ is a uniform force (independent of the position) and the $z$ axis is aligned with the force
$$
W_{AB} = {\bf F} \cdot ({\bf r}(B) - {\bf r}(A)) = F_z (z(B)-z(A))
$$
Therefore, if the force points downwards ($F_z = -mg$), the work to go from a point at height $z(A)$ to another point at a higher height $z(B)=z(A)+h$ ($h>0$) is
$$
W_{AB} = -mgh$$, a negative quantity because the displacement is opposite to the force.
Thus, if we chose $U(A)$ as our reference potential energy,
$$
U(B) = -W_{AB} = +mgh
$$
When we apply the conservation of energy principle between point $A$, where the potential energy has been taken zero, and point $B$, where the kinetic energy vanishes, we have
$$
E =K(A)= \frac12 m v^2(A) =  U(B) = mgh.
$$
Notice that the same result, with the same sign, would be obtained if the direction of the $z$ axis were chosen in the reversed direction. Indeed, the component of the force would change its sign, but the height difference will do the same. In a way, the scalar nature of the work ensures its invariance with respect to a reflection in a $x-y$ plane. However, this is not equivalent to saying that signs should not be used. If the height of point $B$ is lower than point $A$ ($z(B)=z(A)-h$, with $h>0$), $U(B)=-mgh$, again independently of the choice of the axis direction.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the equation of motion

**case I**

$$m\ddot h=-m\,g$$
the solution with the initial conditions $~h(0)=0~,\dot h(0)=v_0~$ is

$$h(t)=v_0\,t-\frac g2\,t^2$$

from here to obtain $~h_{\rm max}~$
you solve this two equations

$$h(t)=h_{\rm max}~,\dot h=0$$

for $~t_{\rm max}~$ and $~h_{\rm max}~$

$$h_{\rm max}=\frac 12 \frac {v_0^2}{g}\quad,
t_{\rm max}=\frac {v_0}{g}\quad, g=9.81$$

**case II**

$$m\ddot h=-m\,(-g)=m\,g$$

the solution

$$h(t)=v_0\,t+\frac g2\,t^2$$

thus

$$h_{\rm max}=-\frac 12 \frac {v_0^2}{g}\quad,
t_{\rm max}=-\frac {v_0}{g}\quad, g=9.81$$

but the time $~t_{\rm max}~$  can not be negative ! this mean that g negative is wrong assumption